# publish android app for a client with my package name prefix

Tags: android, package

I am a newbie android developer, my latest app has package name of **com.myWebsite.appName**, is that ok since it will be uploaded to the client google play account, or should I change it to **com.clientWebsite.appName**

I will create my own developer account very soon, and I want to make sure that won't cause me problems in future when I use **com.myWebsite** in my package in future and upload them to my own personal account

Thank you

**MORE CLARIFICATION**

So can I have **com.myWebiste.appName1** under a developer account and **com.myWebsite.appName2** under another developer account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spend some time and go through [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing#publishing-configure) on Android package names. The store requires each app to have a unique package name hence the need to use **com.clientWebsite.appName** in the event that in future you may need to publish your own app with **com.myWebsite.appName** as its package. We've all been there

Comment: I have checked that link previously, and I know I can't use same package twice, however let me clear my question a bit. My question is about the the package prefix (website) while last part (appName) is different, So can I have **com.myWebiste.appName1** under a developer account and **com.myWebsite.appName2** under another developer account ?

Comment: Thank you very much